# error creating python table using Agate library

Tags: python

I am using the Agate library to create a table.

Using the command as :

```
table = agate.Table(cpi_rows, cpi_types, cpi_titles)
```

Sample values are as below :

```
cpi_rows[0] 
[1.0,'Denmark','DNK',128.0,'EU',1.0,91.0,7.0,2.2,87.0,95.0,83.0,98.0,0.0,97.0,0.0,96.0,98.0,0.0,87.0,89.0,88.0,83.0,0.0,0.0,0.0]

cpi_tiles
['Country Rank','Country / Territory','WB Code','IFS Code','Region','Country Rank','CPI 2013 Score', 'Surveys Used','Standard Error', '90% Confidence interval Lower', 'Upper','Scores range MIN','MAX','Data sources AFDB','BF (SGI)','BF (BTI)','IMD','ICRG','WB','WEF','WJP','EIU','GI','PERC','TI','FH']
```

When I run the command, I am getting the error as :

```
ValueError: Column names must be strings or None.
```

Though all the names in cpi_titles are type strings only, I am unable to get the cause for error.

Answer (score 1):

Just tried your code, and apart from a few corrections to names and stuff this worked without a problem

```
cpi_rows = [[]]
cpi_rows[0] =[1.0,'Denmark','DNK',128.0,'EU',1.0,91.0,7.0,2.2,87.0,95.0,83.0,98.0,0.0,97.0,0.0,96.0,98.0,0.0,87.0,89.0,88.0,83.0,0.0,0.0,0.0]

cpi_titles = ['Country Rank','Country / Territory','WB Code','IFS Code','Region','Country Rank','CPI 2013 Score', 'Surveys Used','Standard Error', '90% Confidence interval Lower', 'Upper','Scores range MIN','MAX','Data sources AFDB','BF (SGI)','BF (BTI)','IMD','ICRG','WB','WEF','WJP','EIU','GI','PERC','TI','FH']

table = agate.Table(cpi_rows, cpi_titles)
print table.print_structure()
```

The output is

```
| column                        | data_type |
| ----------------------------- | --------- |
| Country Rank                  | Number    |
| Country / Territory           | Text      |
| WB Code                       | Text      |
| IFS Code                      | Number    |
| Region                        | Text      |
| Country Rank_2                | Number    |
| CPI 2013 Score                | Number    |
| Surveys Used                  | Number    |
| Standard Error                | Number    |
| 90% Confidence interval Lower | Number    |
| Upper                         | Number    |
| Scores range MIN              | Number    |
| MAX                           | Number    |
| Data sources AFDB             | Number    |
| BF (SGI)                      | Number    |
| BF (BTI)                      | Number    |
| IMD                           | Number    |
| ICRG                          | Number    |
| WB                            | Number    |
| WEF                           | Number    |
| WJP                           | Number    |
| EIU                           | Number    |
| GI                            | Number    |
| PERC                          | Number    |
| TI                            | Number    |
| FH                            | Number    |
```

Obviously, I don't have your definition of types which you want to apply to this data.  The only other thing to note is that you have defined `Country Rank` twice in your column titles so Agate does warn you about this and relabel it.